# Programmatically determine whether a window is standalone or orphaned

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, dom-events

I have a need to figure out whether a window was opened as a standalone vs. whether it was orphaned.  Let me illustrate what I mean.

Let's say I have two ASP pages that I'll call PARENT.asp and CHILD.asp.  Additionally, there is a redirect page that I'll call CHILD-REDIRECT.asp.

When a certain button on CHILD.asp is clicked, it redirects to CHILD-REDIRECT.asp, which includes client-side Javascript code that needs to run a certain way, depending on whether or not it has a parent (based on `window.opener == null`).  For sake of illustration, I'll say the Javascript code is a Boolean variable that I'll call `IsOrphan`.

So, I open a new browser window and I navigate to CHILD.asp.  I then click the button that redirects to CHILD-REDIRECT.asp and kicks off the Javascript.  Because I opened it as a standalone page, `IsOrphan = FALSE`.

Now, I open a new browser and navigate to PARENT.asp.  This page includes a `window.open` call that opens CHILD.asp in a new window.  While CHILD.asp is open, I close PARENT.asp so that CHILD.asp is now in an orphaned window.  So now when I click the button and the page redirects to CHILD-REDIRECT.asp, I need `IsOrphan = TRUE`.

Any thoughts as to how to do this?  I'm looking into setting a variable for the parent via window.opener on the CHILD.asp `onload` event; however, because of the complexity of these pages, this isn't as easy as it sounds.  As it stands now, the Javascript checks `window.opener` to kick off the code, but of course, it doesn't know the difference between a standalone page and an orphaned page.  I'm hoping that someone out there knows of a good/better way to do this.

Comment: do you have control over both pages? are they on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, I have control, and they are on the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work.

In my CHILD.asp page, I set up the following at the top of the page:

```
<script>
   var isChild;
   if (window.opener == null) { isChild = false } else { isChild = true }
</script>
```

This instantiates the isChild client-side variable when the page loads.

My server-side classic ASP code contains something that looks like this:

```
response.write("javascript: if (1=1) { window.location.href='CHILD-REDIRECT.asp?ID=" & someID & "';")
```

I have to admit that one of my hangups was how to send this to the server-side code.  However, I then realized that this would be a moot point, because the client-side value should be there when it rendered.

So, I rewrote it like this:

```
response.write("javascript: if (1=1) { window.location.href='CHILD-REDIRECT.asp?ID=" & someID & "&isChild=' + isChild;")
```

In the CHILD-REDIRECT.asp, I added:

```
var boolChild = <%request.QueryString("isChild")%>
```

So now, I have a flag that indicates whether or not the page was generated by a parent.  Later in the code, I have this:

```
if (window.opener == null && boolChild) { 
   // do something 
}
```

Sure enough, it's doing what I need it to do.