# SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error -- Javascript code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting a "SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error" for simply defining a small piece of Javascript.  This thing works in all browsers EXCEPT IE (yeah, freaking IE -- don't get me started).  I am testing this in IE10, but I was told that this is also happening in IE11.

This is all I have in my code where it's failing (!!!):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isChild;
    if (window.opener == null) { isChild = false } else { isChild = true }
</script>
```

I've looked at other posts that have this same error.  None of them answers my question.

Ideas, anyone?!?

Comment: put semi-colons after isChild = false and isChild = true

Comment: `window.opener` is not supported in IE if the opener is in a different security zone. Check your levels of security in IE and see if the problem occurs again.

Comment: Ciprian: this is a nonissue.  This is intranet code, and the window.opener is on the same domain.  Also, window.opener is central to the issue I'm working on.

Comment: @AmmarCSE: ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion) makes that totally unnecessary. (Best practice, in my view, but definitely not the problem.)

Comment: Side note: It's not the problem, but the above can be markedly simplified/shortened: `var isChild = window.opener != null;` :-)

Comment: @RayK.: That's bizarre. Can you do up a very simple parent page and child page that causes the problem at your end (e.g., an [MCVE](/help/mcve)) and post those to the question? The above seems really straightforward, shouldn't be causing a problem.

Comment: @AmmarCSE: Ah! If it's new info, I should say that ASI = "Automatic Semicolon Insertion". In short: The JavaScript engine will insert semicolons for you as part of the parsing process. (I'm not a fan of it, but they didn't ask me. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: This is related to a question I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565189/programmatically-determine-whether-a-window-is-standalone-or-orphaned -- don't know whether or not that helps.  Also, I like your answer about shortening the code; I might give that a shot!

Comment: @RayK.: :-) Glad that was useful. Re the MCVE, probably best to replicate with a really, really simple parent and child page -- straight HTML, no ASP, etc. They'd each be only a few lines long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have since discovered that IE spits out this generic error if it doesn't like a piece of Javascript code.

I don't remember specifically what the Javascript issue was for this question, but I do remember that once I resolved it, this error went away.

**EDIT:** I seem to keep getting downvotes on this, so let me clarify what I'm talking about. What I'm saying is that a Javascript error -- ANY Javascript error, not something specific -- will cause the SCRIPT16389 error to appear. If you resolve the error -- whatever it is you're getting -- then the SCRIPT16389 should disappear.

Comment: I was getting the same error and resolved by clear cache and cookies of the IE Browser. Might be this help someone how has the same kind of issue :).

Comment: Maybe, but from a UX/UI perspective, do you really think it's feasible to continually ask an end user to clear their cookies and cache?

Comment: I think @imdadhusen had some real error, and when he fixed it the error in IE did not vanish until he cleared the browser cache