# React Redirect throws unspecified error in outlook webview

Tags: reactjs, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing office outlook add-in using reactjs, however I am received the following error.

> SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error

The error occurred after I added routing redirect to the add-in. I created a sample to reproduce the error and you can find the code below.

Taskpane.html

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. -->
<!-- See LICENSE in the project root for license information -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="javascript">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Contoso Task Pane Add-in</title>

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script>
        window.backupHistoryFunctions = {};
        window.backupHistoryFunctions.pushState = window.history.pushState;
        window.backupHistoryFunctions.replaceState = window.history.replaceState;
      </script>
      <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js">
      </script>
      <script>      
        window.history.pushState = window.backupHistoryFunctions.pushState;
        window.history.replaceState = window.backupHistoryFunctions.replaceState;
        console.log(window.history.replaceState)
      </script>

    <!-- For more information on Fluent UI, visit https://developer.microsoft.com/fluentui#/. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css"/>

    <!-- Template styles -->
    <link href="taskpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body class="ms-font-m ms-Fabric">
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

App.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Button, ButtonType } from "office-ui-fabric-react";
import Header from "./Header";
import HeroList from "./HeroList";
import Progress from "./Progress";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import BodyList from "./Body";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      listItems: [],
      redirect: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      listItems: [
        {
          icon: "Ribbon",
          primaryText: "Achieve more with Office integration",
        },
        {
          icon: "Unlock",
          primaryText: "Unlock features and functionality",
        },
        {
          icon: "Design",
          primaryText: "Create and visualize like a pro",
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  switchComponent() {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/login" />; // this causing the error.
    }
  }

  click = async () => {
    this.setState({ redirect: true });
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    console.log("redirect");
  };

  render() {
    const { title, isOfficeInitialized } = this.props;

    if (!isOfficeInitialized) {
      return (
        <Progress title={title} logo="assets/logo-filled.png" message="Please sideload your addin to see app body." />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="ms-welcome">
        <Header logo="assets/logo-filled.png" title={this.props.title} message="Welcome" />
        <HeroList message="Discover what Office Add-ins can do for you today!" items={this.state.listItems}>
          <p className="ms-font-l">
            Modify the source files, then click <b>Run</b>.
          </p>
          <Button
            className="ms-welcome__action"
            buttonType={ButtonType.hero}
            iconProps={{ iconName: "ChevronRight" }}
            onClick={this.click.bind(this)}
          >
            Run
          </Button>
        </HeroList>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login">
              <BodyList />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          {this.switchComponent()}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  isOfficeInitialized: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

Is there a way to solve this or is there any alternative to routing in react ?

Comment: Do you use IE? If yes, can you try with different browser? Read this question, maybe it is helping you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802481/script16389-unspecified-error-javascript-code

Comment: For Office, including Outlook web addins, you can check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins for the browser that is used for the webview.